# In Python pandas, is there a way to improve the speed of dataframe to dict conversion?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to convert DataFrames with 1M rows to a dict. The standard pandas method is quite long to run.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col": np.ones(100000)})
%time dict = df.to_dict(orient="index").values()

CPU times: user 5.88 s, sys: 81.3 ms, total: 5.96 s
Wall time: 6.23 s
```

Is there a way to improve the speed of this process?

Comment: If all you want are the values, use `df.to_dict(orient="r")`, should be faster.

Comment: So why do you need this ? May I know the purpose. I mean why individual every row as a dictionary?

Comment: Well I have a function that takes input data as JSON with a format ‘table’ briefly described here(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) customized to manage date, dict and list columns. I need to generate this data format from dataframes loaded from large csv for testing purposes. And my tests take too long for data preparation right now. @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ suggestion has already improved things!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need are the values, using `orient='records'` drastically improves performance.

```
In [43]: %timeit df.to_dict('i').values()
1 loop, best of 3: 6.23 s per loop

In [42]: %timeit df.to_dict('r')
1 loop, best of 3: 822 ms per loop
```

`'r'` is an alias for `'records'`.

Also, note the advantage of using `r` is that the result is already as a list, while with the former, you'll need to convert the `dict_values` to a `list` after.